# When I open zsh, some weird characters display as my prompt (oh-my-zsh on OSX)

Tags: macos, zsh

I installed oh-my-zsh and now every time I open the terminal some characters display instead of the prompt. However, when I start typing something, the prompt shows correctly:

```
Last login: Wed Oct  5 14:02:50 on ttys000
P~
Last login: Wed Oct  5 14:03:27 on ttys000
P~?
Last login: Wed Oct  5 14:03:37 on ttys000
P~3
Last login: Wed Oct  5 14:04:09 on ttys000
➜  ~  ls
Desktop   Documents Downloads Library   Movies    Music     Pictures  Public
➜  ~
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you have `$PS1` or `precmd` set to something that's incompatible with your shell.  `echo "$PS1"` and `type precmd` will tell you what they're set to.  I'm not sure where in oh-my-zsh they'd be getting set.